# Query to filter comma separated string table entry with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a table with the following columns:

> equipment_id | equipment_name | department_id

department_id is stored with comma separated string of ids (i.e. 1,4,5,7)

Given a department_id I'd like to get all equipment items that are associated with that dept id.

Just wondering if there's an elegant way to write the query or do I have to grab each equipment item, split the department_id column, check if the id matches, and add the equipment item back to a separate list?

Answer (score 1):

Is there anyway to get the data normalized properly?  A single column should never contain a comma seperated string of ids.

Otherwise, most answers to your specific question will perform poorly compared to a properly normalized database.

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I've been given to work with.  It's possible for me to normalize it and if I went that route, I suppose I'd have to look into ways of automating the process.

Comment: tell that to the makers of the profile api in the .net framework - delmited strings stored in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options here

1. Split with a UDF that returns a list of integers. You map this UDF in EF and call it directly.
2. Split in code after its returned. If you use a repository layer for that item the impact on the callers is minimal as all they do is request it from your repository which handles the splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will return all records that contain a particular department_id.

```
var start = department_id + ",";
var end = "," + department_id;
var contains = "," + department_id + ",";

var results = from e in context.Equipment
              where (e.department_id.StartsWith(start)
              || e.department_id.EndsWith(end)
              || e.department_id.Contains(contains)
              || e.department_id.Equals(department_id))
              select e;
```